# Can I create links with 'target="_blank"' in Markdown?

Tags: html, hyperlink, markdown, target, new-window

Is there a way to create a link in Markdown that opens in a new window? If not, what syntax do you recommend to do this? I'll add it to the markdown compiler I use. I think it should be an option.

Comment: So as pointed out in the answers, it is not a feature in markdown. If you wanted to make this a default sitewide to link out, David Morrow has the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8000171/1120027). Or if you just wanted to do it in one instance, then Matchu's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4425223/1120027) says that you must actually write that in HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Markdown open a new window link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492153/markdown-open-a-new-window-link)

Comment: Your question isn't specific about what you're doing, but some markdown engines or browsers (not sure which) recognize when the link you're creating is pointing to a different domain and will open those in a new tab. For me, there are times when removing the `s` from the `https:` is enough to get the functionality I want.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

As far as the Markdown syntax is concerned, if you want to get that detailed, you'll just have to use HTML.

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Hello, world!</a>
```

Most Markdown engines I've seen allow plain old HTML, just for situations like this where a generic text markup system just won't cut it. (The StackOverflow engine, for example.) They then run the entire output through an HTML whitelist filter, regardless, since even a Markdown-only document can easily contain XSS attacks. As such, if you or your users want to create `_blank` links, then they probably still can.

If that's a feature you're going to be using often, it might make sense to create your own syntax, but it's generally not a vital feature. If I want to launch that link in a new window, I'll ctrl-click it myself, thanks.

Comment: Ya know what? I agree with you and [alex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/markdown-target-blank/4425214#4425214). I decided not to use `_blank` at all. It's a better user experience to keep things in one browser. They can just hit back or command-click (Mac user here :)), like you say.

Comment: I have javascript run on the page that adds _blank to all links outside of my domain. like @alex has in the next answer

Comment: I would suggest (in the desire of being explicit and inline readable) the following syntax: `[Visit this page](http::/link.com(` to get the idea of *opening*.

Comment: Simple target="_blank" may be dangerous! Add also rel="noopener" into the tag! (https://sites.google.com/site/bughunteruniversity/nonvuln/phishing-with-window-opener)

Comment: @MaxVyaznikov Interesting. Do you think it would be safer if browsers provided an above the edge pop up window for login? Separate the login UI for websites from spoofed and fake login UI created by "lookalike" web pages. It might be more possible now where it was more difficult in the past.

Comment: Concerning hitting the back button... with Rmarkdown, in my experience if the link is not found, the back button closes the app/doc completely.

Comment: unfortunately the <a> tag using target="_blank" did not work for me, opens the link the same tab :(  At least when the file was on github.

Comment: This doesn't work in markdown, it still opens in the same tab.

Comment: Would be a great answer, but does not work on github Wiki pages (which unconditionally strips out `target="_blank"`, possibly due to _possibly unfounded_ security concerns).

Comment: It's really not always a better user experience to keep things in one browser... What if they are in a sign-up or check-out flow in your SPA, and at the last step they need to agree to some conditions in an external page? Unless you use a modal, opening in a new window would really be preferable to the user completely losing context and having to go through the whole process again.

Comment: @DaveLand, before stating something is unfounded best to do a little research. This little sample page of possible issue may be an eye-opener if you haven't got latest/greatest browsers: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Comment: @DaveLand I'd just like to take a minute to say hi to another Dave Land (my name too). I've never met one before! You seem quite handsome and clever. At first I read your comment and thought "man I don't remember making that comment". Then I was like "wait, my stack overflow username is not Dave Land". Then I realized I'm not as alone in the universe as I thought...sniff...

Answer (score 520):

[Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/) supports it. It's compatible with standard Markdown syntax, but has many extensions, too. You would use it like this:

```
[link](url){:target="_blank"}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work using the Markdown engine on Mac :-(

Comment: I didn't wanna use html inside markdown, it really looks a bit nasty. But this method is awesome. Thank You!

Comment: Works great with jekyll!

Comment: The [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/) syntax: 

  [link name](url_link){:target="_blank"}

can be parsed into HTML using the kramdown online editor:

[http://trykramdown.herokuapp.com/](http://trykramdown.herokuapp.com/)

I used it because I already had quite a few kramdown references, and wanted to avoid retyping them.

Comment: Is there a way in jekyll to set this as the default? I'd like all the links in my blog posts to open with `target="_blank"`

Comment: It doesn't work. It just renders the {:target="_blank"} as text.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that (at least in vscode) '_' is interpreted as the beginning of a span of italic text.  When there is no closing '_', it malprocesses the md.

Comment: for those who are interested: this does not work neither for Jupyter Notebook nor for Python Dash (version 0.39.0)

Comment: Works great with Pelican ! Tx !

Comment: In Safari running JupyterHub, no need for the {:target="_blank"}.

Comment: It works without the colon ':' for me: [link](url){target="_blank"}
I use lume as a site generator, it uses markdown-it rpm package.

Comment: This did the trick!  For using with pandoc, you can just pipe it like so:
```kramdown myfile.md | pandoc -o myfile.html -f markdown -t html```

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box with Wiki.js for those curious.

Answer (score 135):

I don't think there is a markdown feature, although there may be other options available if you want to open links which point outside your own site automatically with JavaScript.

```
Array.from(document.links)
    .filter(link => link.hostname != window.location.hostname)
    .forEach(link => link.target = '_blank');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdSVn/).

If you're using jQuery:

```
$(document.links).filter(function() {
    return this.hostname != window.location.hostname;
}).attr('target', '_blank');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j2mk/).

Comment: i agree with you but on the occasion that you are in an iframe you need to blast out of the frame with the link.

Comment: I find the only time I force people into a new window is when I'm halfway through a sentence linking somewhere external, and I want to provide sources for my comments without interrupting the flow. This js snippet is *ideal* for the purpose - thanks, upvoted :)

Comment: I think that quote from Jakob Nielson doesn't apply here anymore. He complains about opening new windows, but nowadays target="_blank" opens in a new tab instead. I personally don't like it when links to other domains don't open in new tabs.

Comment: Because he clearly doesn't understand, or appreciate, the importance of style and design for usability - which when taken seriously may well conflict with some of the mechanistic concepts he is so fond of. He fails to see that building a great website requires humble pragmatism much more than dogmatic obedience. I agree that there are many sites which would be well served by following his recommendations - but if you want polish you cannot avoid breaking his commandments. That and the ridiculous deification.

Comment: Also: because saying `Jakob Nielsen says you shouldn't do that` is a terrible argument.

Comment: Not sure where the "answer" in context was here. You started with a comment about UX, which is erroneous (Jakob Nielsen is full of it here, not worth my time arguing about it though). And then ended up discussing Javascript, though markdown was the context.

Comment: Removed unpopular opinion.

Comment: I'm going to add here that THIS is also preferable as a global solution. It keeps your Markdown clean, which is the point of Markdown.

Comment: catch a bug, for plain javascript, shoule be: `javascript.links` -> `document.links` ?

Answer (score 95):

With Markdown v2.5.2, you can use this:

```
[link](URL){:target="_blank"}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me.  Using with django 1.6

Comment: Works with Jekyll v2.4.0 (might work with earlier versions as well)

Comment: This is kramdown (and as Jekyll uses kramdown, it works with Jekyll).

Comment: Cannot seem to get this syntax to work in GitLab.  I'm not sure which version of Markdown is currently in use.

Comment: Is there a way of making this the default so I don't have to specify it for every link?

Comment: worked with jekyll 3.7.2. Also learned if you want to use with inline style you can use **Markdown** like this 
`[Link](https://example.org/){:target="_blank"}{:style="color: pink; font-size:20px;"}`

Comment: for those who are interested: this does not work neither for Jupyter Notebook nor for Python Dash (version 0.39.0)

Comment: Work with MkDocs 1.2.*, thanks for this answer, should be accepted as the best.

Comment: I found that the underscore `_` is optional.  Using `{:target="blank"}` works the same.  And in my buggy text editor, the underscore makes the rest of the file look italic

Comment: Works for `mkdocs` but you have to enable the `attr_list` extension, see https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1958

Comment: Works with @Nuxt/Content

Answer (score 29):

So, it isn't quite true that you cannot add link attributes to a Markdown URL. To add attributes, check with the underlying markdown parser being used and what their extensions are.

In particular, [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/) has an extension to enable [`link_attributes`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-link_attributes), which allow markup in the link. e.g.

```
[Hello, world!](http://example.com/){target="_blank"}
```

- For those coming from *R* (e.g. using `rmarkdown`, `bookdown`, `blogdown` and so on), this is the syntax you want.
- For those not using *R*, you may need to [enable the extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions) in the call to `pandoc` with `+link_attributes`

**Note:** This is different than the [`kramdown`](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#inline-links) parser's support, which is one the accepted answers above. In particular, note that kramdown differs from pandoc since it requires a colon -- `:` -- at the start of the curly brackets -- `{}`, e.g.

```
[link](http://example.com){:hreflang="de"}
```

In particular:

```
# Pandoc
{ attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2"}

# Kramdown
{: attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2"}
 ^
 ^ Colon
```

Comment: This worked for me in our custom markdown environment.  Thanks!

Comment: What about for reference links?

Comment: `{target="_blank"}` works if you try to specify it in Wiki.js. For those that are curious. This helped me get the functionality I wanted for specific links.

Answer (score 18):

One global solution is to put `<base target="_blank">`
into your page's `<head>` element. That effectively adds a default target to every anchor element. I use markdown to create content on my Wordpress-based web site, and my theme customizer will let me inject that code into the top of every page. If your theme doesn't do that, there's a [plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/)

Answer (score 13):

Not a direct answer, but may help some people ending up here.

If you are using [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) there is a plugin that automatically adds `target="_blank"` to external links in your markdown.

It's called [gatsby-remark-external-links](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-external-links/) and is used like so:

`yarn add gatsby-remark-external-links`

```js
plugins: [      
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    options: {
      plugins: [{
        resolve: "gatsby-remark-external-links",
        options: {
          target: "_blank",
          rel: "noopener noreferrer"
        }
      }]
    }
  },
```

It also takes care of the `rel="noopener noreferrer"`.

Reference the docs if you need more options.

Answer (score 12):

For ghost markdown use:

```
[Google](https://google.com" target="_blank)
```

Found it here:
https://cmatskas.com/open-external-links-in-a-new-window-ghost/

Comment: i like your solution. as i've tried it with different configurations it seems that it only works in _inline linking_. maybe there is a way for linking with _reference links_. something like:
`[open new window][1] \n [1]: (https://abc.xyz" target="_blank)`. maybe i mistake something, or this isn't ment to work that way?

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Grav CMS and this works perfectly:

Body/Content:
`Some text[1]`

Body/Reference:
`[1]: http://somelink.com/?target=_blank`

Just make sure that the target attribute is passed first, if there are additional attributes in the link, copy/paste them to the end of the reference URL.

Also work as direct link:
`[Go to this page](http://somelink.com/?target=_blank)`

Comment: For reference, here is the [relevant documentation chapter](https://learn.getgrav.org/content/linking#link-attributes).

Comment: Thanks.  This still works if the url already has query parameters too, adding `&target=_blank`:  `[Go to this page](http://somelink.com/?param=42&target=_blank)`

Answer (score 7):

You can do this via native javascript code like so:

```
 
var pattern = /a href=/g;
var sanitizedMarkDownText = rawMarkDownText.replace(pattern,"a target='_blank' href=");
```

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/dgtlmonk/2c2GQ/7/)

Answer (score 7):

In my project I'm doing this and it works fine:

```
[Link](https://example.org/ "title" target="_blank")
```

[Link](https://example.org/)

But not all parsers let you do that.

Comment: Almost works, but even your example renders with url encoded into the title attr, rather than as new attrs (view source or edit the node as html):  `<a href="https://example.org/" rel="nofollow" title="title&quot; target=&quot;_blank">Link</a>`

Answer (score 7):

There's no easy way to do it, and like @alex has noted you'll need to use JavaScript. His answer is the best solution but in order to optimize it, you might want to filter only to the post-content links.

```
<script>
    var links = document.querySelectorAll( '.post-content a' );  
    for (var i = 0, length = links.length; i < length; i++) {  
        if (links[i].hostname != window.location.hostname) {
            links[i].target = '_blank';
        }
    }
</script>
```

The code is compatible with IE8+ and you can add it to the bottom of your page. Note that you'll need to change the ".post-content a" to the class that you're using for your posts.

As seen here: http://blog.hubii.com/target-_blank-for-links-on-ghost/

Answer (score 3):

If someone is looking for a **global `rmarkdown` (`pandoc`) solution**.

##### Using Pandoc Lua Filter

You could write your own [Pandoc Lua Filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) which adds `target="_blank"` to all links:

1. Write a Pandoc Lua Filter, name it for example `links.lua`

```lua
function Link(element)

    if 
        string.sub(element.target, 1, 1) ~= "#"
    then
        element.attributes.target = "_blank"
    end
    return element

end
```

2. Then update your `_output.yml`

```yaml
bookdown::gitbook:
  pandoc_args:
    - --lua-filter=links.lua
```

---

##### Inject `<base target="_blank">` in Header

An alternative solution would be to inject [`<base target="_blank">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) in the HTML `head` section using the [`includes`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html) option:

1. Create a new HTML file, name it for example `links.html`

```html
<base target="_blank">
```

2. Then update your `_output.yml`

```yaml
bookdown::gitbook:
  includes:
    in_header: links.html
```

Note: This solution may also open new tabs for hash (`#`) pointers/URLs. I have not tested this solution with such URLs.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel I solved it this way:

```
$post->text= Str::replace('<a ', '<a target="_blank"', $post->text);
```

Not works for a specific link. Edit all links in the Markdown text. (In my case it's fine)

Answer (score 1):

If you work with [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/), you might be interested in the [Open in a new tab - plugin](https://newtab.kubaandrysek.cz/)

This plugin adds JS to open outgoing links and PDFs in a new tab.

Install the plugin using pip from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mkdocs-open-in-new-tab/):

```bash
pip3 install mkdocs-open-in-new-tab
```

Just add the plugin:

```yaml
plugins:
  - search
  - open-in-new-tab
```

More about the [plugin](https://newtab.kubaandrysek.cz/).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when trying to implement markdown using PHP.

Since the user generated links created with markdown need to open in a new tab but site links need to stay in tab I changed markdown to only generate links that open in a new tab. So not all links on the page link out, just the ones that use markdown.

In markdown I changed all the link output to be `<a target='_blank' href="...">` which was easy enough using find/replace.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree that it's a better user experience to stay within one browser tab.  If you want people to stay on your site, or come back to finish reading that article, send them off in a new tab.

Building on @davidmorrow's answer, throw this javascript into your site and turn just external links into links with target=_blank:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      // Creating custom :external selector
      $.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
          return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
                  && (obj.hostname != location.hostname);
      };

      $(function(){
        // Add 'external' CSS class to all external links
        $('a:external').addClass('external');

        // turn target into target=_blank for elements w external class
        $(".external").attr('target','_blank');

      })

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Automated for external links only, using GNU sed & make

If one would like to do this systematically for all external links, [CSS is no option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281527/2192488). However, one could run the following [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) command once the (X)HTML has been created from Markdown:

```
sed -i 's|href="http|target="_blank" href="http|g' index.html
```

This can be further automated by adding above `sed` command to a `makefile`. For details, see GNU [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [see how I have done that](https://hamwaves.com/index/en/makefile) on [my website](https://hamwaves.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add any attributes using {[attr]="[prop]"}

For example [Google] (http://www.google.com){target="_blank"}

Answer (score 0):

For completed alex answered (Dec 13 '10)

A more smart injection target could be done with this code :

```
/*
 * For all links in the current page...
 */
$(document.links).filter(function() {
    /*
     * ...keep them without `target` already setted...
     */
    return !this.target;
}).filter(function() {
    /*
     * ...and keep them are not on current domain...
     */
    return this.hostname !== window.location.hostname ||
        /*
         * ...or are not a web file (.pdf, .jpg, .png, .js, .mp4, etc.).
         */
        /\.(?!html?|php3?|aspx?)([a-z]{0,3}|[a-zt]{0,4})$/.test(this.pathname);
/*
 * For all link kept, add the `target="_blank"` attribute. 
 */
}).attr('target', '_blank');
```

You could change the regexp exceptions with adding more extension in `(?!html?|php3?|aspx?)` group construct (understand this regexp here: https://regex101.com/r/sE6gT9/3).

and for a without jQuery version, check code below:

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (!links[i].target) {
        if (
            links[i].hostname !== window.location.hostname || 
            /\.(?!html?)([a-z]{0,3}|[a-zt]{0,4})$/.test(links[i].pathname)
        ) {
            links[i].target = '_blank';
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do this in a specific link, just use the inline attribute list syntax as others have answered, or just use HTML.

If you want to do this in all generated `<a>` tags, depends on your Markdown compiler, maybe you need an extension of it.

I am doing this for my blog these days, which is generated by `pelican`, which use `Python-Markdown`. And I found an extension for `Python-Markdown` [Phuker/markdown_link_attr_modifier](https://github.com/Phuker/markdown_link_attr_modifier), it works well. Note that an old extension called `newtab` seems not work in Python-Markdown 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

## For `React` + `Markdown` environment:

I created a reusable component:

```js
export type TargetBlankLinkProps = {
  label?: string;
  href?: string;
};

export const TargetBlankLink = ({
  label = "",
  href = "",
}: TargetBlankLinkProps) => (
  <a href={href} target="__blank">
    {label}
  </a>
);
```

And I use it wherever I need a link that open in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

For "markdown-to-jsx" with MUI v5

This seem to work for me:

```
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
```

...

```
  const MarkdownLink = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <Link {...props}>{children}</Link>
  );
```

...

```
          <Markdown
            options={{
              forceBlock: true,
              overrides: {
                a: {
                  component: MarkdownLink,
                  props: {
                    target: '_blank',
                  },
                },
              },
            }}
          >
            {description}
          </Markdown>
```

Answer (score -3):

This works for me: [Page Link](your url here "(target|_blank)")