# Jekyll: produce custom HTML for external links (target and CSS class)

Tags: css, jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I understand that the `target` attribute of an `<a>` link cannot be specified by CSS. I would like to be able to generate external links in a Jekyll based markdown document with the following output:

```
<a href="the-url" class="external" target="_blank">the text</a>
```

*without* resorting to something like this:

```
[the text](the url){:target"_blank" class="external"}
```

I don't want to hard-code the `target` in each link, because I might want to change it at some point, also it's noisy. So ideally I would have

```
[the text](the url){:class="external"}
```

...but then CSS cannot add the `target="_blank"`.

So my idea would be a custom plugin that allows me to write

```
{% ext-link the-url the text %}
```

Does such a plugin exist? Are there better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems writing a plugin is straight forward. This is what I have come up with:

```
module Jekyll
  class ExtLinkTag < Liquid::Tag
    @text = ''
    @link = ''

    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
      if markup =~ /(.+)(\s+(https?:\S+))/i
        @text = $1
        @link = $3
      end
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      output = super
      "<a class='external' target='_blank' href='"+@link+"'>"+@text+"</a>"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('extlink', Jekyll::ExtLinkTag)
```

Example usage:

```
Exhibition at {% extlink Forum Stadtpark http://forum.mur.at %}.
```

HTML output:

```
<p>Exhibition at <a class="external" target="_blank" href="http://forum.mur.at">Forum Stadtpark</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 11):

When you need to do this on Github pagesand then cannot use plugins, you can do it with javascript :

```
// any link that is not part of the current domain is modified

(function() {
  var links = document.links;
  for (var i = 0, linksLength = links.length; i < linksLength; i++) {
    // can also be
    //  links[i].hostname != 'subdomain.example.com'
    if (links[i].hostname != window.location.hostname) {
      links[i].target = '_blank';
      links[i].className += ' externalLink';
    }
  }
})();
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425214/1548376).

Answer (score 3):

There is a small Jekyll plugin to apply `target="_blank"`, `rel="nofollow"`, class names, and any other attributes of your choice to external links automatically:

[Jekyll ExtLinks Plugin](http://ogarkov.com/jekyll/plugins/extlinks/)

A list of hosts to be skipped when applying `rel` can be configured if you want to keep some links untouched. This way, you don't have to mangle with Markdown anymore.

UPD: This plugin has been released to RubyGems now: [jekyll-extlinks](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-extlinks). Use `gem install jekyll-extlinks` to install it. Also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/d-ogarkov/jekyll-extlinks).

Comment: Tested on Jekyll 3.4.0, had an issue with nokogiri - fixed by specifying gem 'nokogiri' in the project Gemfile. Other than that, the plugin worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

My plugin can automatically force all external links to open in a new browser.

https://keith-mifsud.me/projects/jekyll-target-blank

And as of v1.1.0 you can also add optional extra CSS class names.