# markdown link opening in new tab

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

Is there a way to open the below markdown link in new tab? I've got some result from [markdown target=“_blank”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/markdown-target-blank#answer-4705645), but in my case it's different have used  **<>** symbol to projected the link.

http://google.com

**Not used the usual format**

> (name)[linkname]

**Used**

> <>

Inside this projected the link name. Is possible to open this link in new tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [markdown target="\_blank"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/markdown-target-blank)

Comment: @sircapsalot my question is different. I've not used "(name )[link]" this following format. I've used "<linkname>" this format to project the link.

Comment: What is to "_project a link_"? What is  `<>` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/) syntax:

```
[link name](url_link){:target="_blank"}
```

can be parsed into HTML using the kramdown online editor: 
https://kramdown.herokuapp.com/
Then you can paste the HTML syntax into your markdown document.
I used it because I already had quite a few kramdown references, and wanted to avoid retyping them in HTML.

Comment: can we use this to open a link in stackoverflow post?
test: [link](www.google.com){:target="_blank"} doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The kramdown syntax won't work in a stackoverflow post directly.  You first have to parse it into HTML using the kramdown online editor: http://trykramdown.herokuapp.com/
For example, I parsed the kramdown code:  

    [google_link](www.google.com){:target="_blank"}  

into HTML code:  

    <p><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">google_link</a></p>  

that can be pasted into a stackoverflow post.

Comment: not working for me. leaves the ```{:target="_blank"}``` as text in the markdown

Comment: I just ran my example on trykramdown and it worked fine as before, without `:target`.

Answer (score 31):

Doing some quick research - Markdown by default does not support this.  Some solutions include using plugins like Kramdown, but I think the best solution is just to use an HTML tag in your markdown file. (as pointed out in the comment above `^`)

```
# Some markdown
*click below*
<a href="example.com" target="_blank">New Tab</a>
...
```

Comment: well it would depend on what site is rendering it. some markdown editors may not support arbitrary html. it all depends.

Comment: I mean on GitHub.

Comment: any solution regards github

Comment: @qrtLs or GitLab

Answer (score 2):

As far as I could find, this is not possible on GitHub currently. See good answer on this from Plaul [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915571/open-link-in-new-tab-with-github-markdown-using-target-blank). I hope they will fix it soon, as it seems searching for an answer that this is something a lot of people would like to see.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to JavaScript, you can run a simple script to handle this for you wherever your markdown is rendered:

```
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
anchors.forEach((a) => {
  a.setAttribute('target', '__blank');
  a.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener noreferrer');
});
```