# open link in new tab with github markdown using target="_blank"

Tags: github, hyperlink, markup

Is there a way to let a Link, written in githubs markdown, open in a new tab?
All posts I have found related to this suggests to use HTML and `target="_blank"`, which is fine with me, but that doesn't work.
For example this link:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Go</a>
```

Does not open in a new tab.
I'm no interested in replies for all kind of different markdown syntaxes, but only in a solution that will work when I write my markdown on github.

Comment: https://github.com/mojombo/github-flavored-markdown/issues/28

Comment: `[go](http://stackoverflow.com){:target="_blank"}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create links with 'target="\_blank"' in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown)

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Well it seems that the simple answer is "It's not possible". Github does not include the target attribute even if you use plain HTML, so it's not a in the final HTML Anchor tag. Annoying, but OK, users can just do a CTRL+click (on Windows and Linux) or CMD+click (on MacOS) on the link, the get the same behavior.

Comment: +1 For not putting some wrong solution like thousands of other people on StackOverflow. You can't open links in a new tab using markdown (c. 2019).

Comment: While the answer is correct `users can just do XYZ` is not a solution to this problem. The behavior wanted is clicking on the link to automatically open in a new tab. The behavior with CTRL or CMD + click is adding 1 additional step.
Further more unfortunately, other UX decision make CTRL/CMD+click unreliable sometime (Javascript link for instance) which means that the user would need to know what is an actual link and what is not. I wish Markdown just read the HTML at least.

Comment: Don't forget middle-click ("scroll-click" for some) with your mouse also works!

Answer (score 23):

There is a solution specific to websites using GitHub pages: adding line

```
markdown: kramdown
```

to file `_config.yml`, you can use `[go](http://stackoverflow.com){:target="_blank" rel="noopener"}` because then GitHub pages engine uses another markdown called [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/) for generating html. However, it does not work on previews and in markdown rendered by GitHub directly in the project repository.

Comment: Do you mean we can open github and open README.md to see the function is work for target _blank?

Comment: only if you have external site using GitHub Pages

Comment: As you said, the links aren't rendered properly on the GitHub Preview, but it worked perfectly after deployed the GitHub page.

Answer (score 3):

From what I have read and researched, it is not possible. I wanted to do something similar but soon realized that it is not a feature in git md, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Till date no feature like that has been captured except on github pages, but it will work when you use ctrl and click the link
Here are when i tried using the _blank attribute
[this is when i try using the _blank attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cegF.png)

[And this is the preview i got on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBLJF.png)

Answer (score -1):

It's possible for Github Pages users (**Jekyll**), the proper way *(March 2022)* is to add to your `_config.yml` file these lines:

```yaml
kramdown:
  input: Kramdown
```

This is specified [in the documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#kramdown-processor):

> You can also change the processor used by Kramdown (as specified for the input key in the Kramdown RDoc). For example, to use the non-GFM Kramdown processor in Jekyll, add the following to your configuration.

Use the Kramdown processor instead of GFM will allow you to add `{:target="_blank" rel="noopener"}` to markdown links to tell the browser to open link in new tab.

#### Example

```markdown
[Stackoverflow The Key](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/){:target="_blank" rel="noopener"}
```

### /!\ Disclaimer

Changing the markdown processor from **GFM** (default value) to **kramdown** can create issues in the HTML result, since all the specific features of GitHub Flavored Markdown (**GFM**) won't work anymore.

Answer (score -22):

The answer should be what @Idavid posted in a comment.

```
[go](http://stackoverflow.com){:target="_blank"}.
```

You should also add rel="noopener"

```
[go](http://stackoverflow.com){:target="_blank" rel="noopener"}
```

Comment: As of 2019-01-11 neither of these approaches work on GitHub. https://github.com/mojombo/github-flavored-markdown/issues/28

Comment: I might have confused github markdown with github pages. I know on github pages it works.

Comment: It works for me in Gitpages. The file in repo is https://github.com/mind-maps/software/blob/master/index.md. Render as https://mind-maps.github.io/software/ with target="_blank"

Comment: The question clear states "in githubs markdown", and this works in the github page generated from the markdown - so it covers the question pretty well IMO (question could be clarified *a little* as to if it refers to the html generated from the markdown as by github). And it solved my need, so upvoting.