# Is it possible to create links with 'target=“_blank”' with GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to create links that open in a new tab in GitHub Flavored Markdown like this `<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">test</a>` . If so, How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Please visit the <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help">help center</a>, take the <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/tour">tour</a> to see what and <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask">How to Ask</a>. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example">minimal reproducible example</a> of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the <code>[&lt;&gt;]</code> snippet editor.</span>

Comment: You can use html in markdown I believe

Comment: Thank you for the help links @jasie

Comment: Don't Github links by default open in a new tab?

Comment: @RolvApneseth I know that it is possibly, but when I tried using GitHub's markdown editor, the links appeared broken.

Comment: GitHub links do not.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42156438/14316282)

Comment: @RolvApneseth it appears that is the case. Possibly put link to the other question as the answer?

Comment: @Spectric they do not.

Comment: Sure I can put it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42156438/14316282) it seems that this is not possible, as Github does not include the `target` attribute even in plain HTML.

As for what I believe is the reasoning, I found [this issue](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1367) on github while browsing, which says that when `target="_blank"` is used without `rel="noreferrer noopener"`, it can present a severe security vulnerability.