# RMarkdown html _site.yml navbar href links, open in new tab with target="_blank"

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

Struggling with R Markdown HTML _site.yml page.  Within my navigation bar, I've got href's pointing to different website links and I can't figure our where to include the

```
target="_blank"
```

statement so links open in a new tab.  Href links don't follow the normal html format in RMarkdowns _site.yml file.

```r
    - text: "TWITTER"
      icon: fa-twitter
      href: https://twitter.com
    - text: "GITHUB"
      icon: fa-github
      href: https://github.com
    - text: "SLACK"
      icon: fa-slack
      href: https://slack.com
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359583/markdown-link-opening-in-new-tab

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm able to use "<a href="example.com" target="_blank">New Tab</a>" links just fine in my HTML files.  I'm specifically looking for a way in my _site.yml navigation file to open links in a new tab on the navigation bar.

Comment: @KevinMagnan did you find a solution by now?

Comment: @jwarz also interested

Comment: @jwarz and RockScience nope, never found a solution to those links just open on the same page.

Comment: @KevinMagnan , jwarz and RockScience I added a solution that works for all external links

Comment: Yeah those both look like good solutions! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a redirect page for each one like this:

```
    - text: "TWITTER"
  icon: fa-twitter
  href: twitter_redirect.html
```

and then for twitter_redirect.html (etc), use window.open followed by window.history.back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
    window.open('https://twitter.com/', '_blank');
    window.history.back();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Finally worked this into my website and it worked like a charm (aside from pesky popup blockers). Thanks!

Comment: That works but it requires to create and maintain an intermediate page. See  Abdessabour's solution which is very elegant

Answer (score 3):

Basically the best course of action is to create a js code that automatically adds `target="_blank"` to any external links. And taking into account the fact that internal links generated by `rmarkdown` are relative. We can easily create a regular expression that test for the existence of an external link then if found append `target="_blank"`

## First create : links.js

```js
(function() {
  for (const link of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) {
    if (/^(https?:)?\/\//.test(link.getAttribute('href'))) link.target = '_blank';
  }
})();
```

## Add a script tag to include_footer.html

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="links.js"></script>
```

## include include_footer in _site.yml

```yaml
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      after_body: include_footer.html
```

Comment: it looks like an elegant solution but I couldnt make it work. Where do you save links.js?
Is it enought to save it to the footer?

Comment: save `link.js` in the same folder with footer. Yeah It'll work if you put the content of the `js` file inside the footer

Comment: @RockScience if you have a js folder then put it in it then change the `src` attrib of `script` tag

Comment: Thank you! For the reference I had to move `links.js` to the *final* location of footer.html (ie: inside subfolder /_site). it now works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Refer the JScode from @Abdessabour Mtk,

````
---  
title: "BookMark"  
output: html_document  
---  

```{r setup, include=FALSE}  
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)  
library(knitr)  
```  

[google](https://www.google.com)  
...

```{js, echo=FALSE}  
(function() {  
  for (const link of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) {  
    if (/^(https?:)?\/\//.test(link.getAttribute('href'))) link.target = '_blank';  
  }  
})();  
```
````