# Bitbucket ticket markdown: open external link in new window (_blank)

Tags: syntax, markdown, bitbucket

What ist the right markdown syntax for opening an external link in a "_blank" window from a bitbucket ticket?

Following versions do not work:

```
[link](http://www.example.com target="_blank")

[link](http://www.example.com){:target="_blank"}

[link](http://www.example.com target="_blank")

<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/markdown-target-blank - duplicated

Comment: thanks but this does'nt work. see my non working examples.

Comment: I expect Bitbucket is stripping out the raw HTML (their competitor, GitHub, certainly does) for security reasons and they mostly likely do not support the other non-standard styles. In order words, you can;t do this on Bitbucket. This is still a duplicate.