# Any alternative for target="_blank" in github?

Tags: html, github, markup

I want to add links to my GitHub readme.md file which will open up a new tab when clicked.

Any other markup that can do this instead of html? `target="_blank"` doesn't work. :(

Most of the answers from other questions don't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [markdown target="\_blank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/markdown-target-blank)

Comment: You cant in markdown. You will need to create a website. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/markdown-target-blank

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript to open the link in a new tab

```
<a href="test.html" onclick="return ! window.open(this.href);">Open in a new window</a>
```