# Markdown target="blank" (html) doesn´t work

Tags: markdown

As you can see  if you click into the image a new tab won't open and you will leave the repo, I have tried _blank but as in markdown _ is for italic I had to use _ but it didn't work,  you can find a shortcut to the whole markdown code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been answered here: [Can I create links with 'target="_blank"' in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown)

From that answer:

> Most Markdown engines I've seen allow plain old HTML, just for situations like this where a generic text markup system just won't cut it. (The StackOverflow engine, for example.) They then run the entire output through an HTML whitelist filter, regardless, since even a Markdown-only document can easily contain XSS attacks. As such, if you or your users want to create _blank links, then they probably still can.