# What's the meaning of adding a target="_blank" attribute in a div?

Tags: html

I saw this code below:

```
<div target="_blank" class="P5DMenuAnimated" style="left: -80.8112px; top: -80.8112px; background-position: left -40px; opacity: 1; width: 40px; height: 40px;" action="clone"></div>
```

I know in hyperlink, target="_blank" means that opening a new window. However, when I click this button, it doesn't open a new window, with some effect in the current page.

Comment: This is not a valid question, you should use google for this

Comment: `<div>` does not have `target` attribute, it's just bad usage of it. Maybe some JS tries to use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [target="\_blank" vs. target="\_new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new) also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` doesn't have `target` attribute 
You can use `target="_blank"` in `<a>`, for example

> The `target` attribute specifies where to open the linked document.
>
> The `target` attribute can have one of the following values:
>
> - `_blank` - Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
> - `_self` - Opens the linked document in the same window/tab as it was clicked (this is default)
> - `_parent` - Opens the linked document in the parent frame
> - `_top` - Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
> - `framename` - Opens the linked document in a named frame which was opened with JavaScript

source: [W3Schools - HTML Links](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem...Im new to html...I just don't know whether div is able to use target attri...