# Docusaurus - how to open external links in new tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, docusaurus

I am using Docusaurus and would like to open external links in new tabs.

I would prefer to use code for this rather than the solution of writing html code in my markdown document as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425223/5502986).

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28089308/5502986):

`[link](url){:target="_blank"}`

As well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862840/5502986):

`[Google](https://google.com" target="_blank)`

I think [this post](https://yihui.name/en/2018/09/target-blank/) would probably do what I want, I tried adding the code to _index.js, but Docusaurus stopped building.

```
(function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (/^(https?:)?\/\//.test(links[i].getAttribute('href'))) {
      links[i].target = '_blank';
    }
  }
})();
```

I uploaded the JavaScript code to [GitHub](https://msdcanderson.github.io/docusaurus-open-link-new-tab.github.io/open-link-new-tab.js) and added it to `siteConfig.js`:

```
// Add custom scripts here that would be placed in <script> tags.
  scripts: [
    "https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js",
    "https://msdcanderson.github.io/docusaurus-open-link-new-tab.github.io/open-link-new-tab.js"
  ],
```

The script seems to load, but doesn't work as expected.

I expect a link written in Markdown to open in a new browser tab:

```
[the rmarkdown website](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com)
```

Any ideas would be great - thanks

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/3309

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### NOTE: This answer is for Docusaurus v1

Docusaurus maintainer here!

You're right that Docusaurus doesn't support this out of the box. The probable reason that your script above doesn't work is because Docusaurus injects the `<script>` tags are above the `<body>` and when the script runs, the `<body>` hasn't loaded and there are no `<a>` tags to operate on. Try wrapping your code in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)` like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (/^(https?:)?\/\//.test(links[i].getAttribute('href'))) {
      links[i].target = '_blank';
    }
  }
});
```

However, I recommend that you don't use that script and instead achieve the effect in a few other ways:

#### 1. Remarkable Plugins

Customize this using Remarkable plugins. Remarkable is the Markdown engine that converts the Markdown to HTML.

This [remarkable-extlink plugin](https://github.com/vitaliy-bobrov/remarkable-extlink) seems to be what you need. Try adding it into your siteConfig! Refer to the siteConfig documentation [here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-config#markdownplugins-array).

```
// siteConfig.js
const extlink = require('remarkable-extlink');

const siteConfig = {
  ...
  markdownPlugins: [
    function(md) {
      extlink(md, {
        host: 'yourhost.com', // The hrefs that you DON'T want to be external
      });
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```

#### 2. Remarkable Options

Remarkable supports making all links external by customizing the [`linkTarget` option](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable/blob/fa88dcac16832ab26f068c30f0c070c3fec0d9da/lib/configs/full.js#L13) and Docusaurus exposes that in `siteConfig` (but isn't documented) and isn't working at the moment. I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/facebook/Docusaurus/pull/1430) to fix this, so look out for it in the next release. However, I wouldn't recommend this approach since it makes **All** your links open in new tab, not just the external ones.

#### 3. Use HTML in your Markdown

Personally I would just use this option as it's the fastest. Also there's nothing wrong/bad about doing this and I love that I can fallback on HTML.

#### 4. Write your own Remarkable Plugin

Write your own plugin that understands such a `[link](url){:target="_blank"}` syntax and generates the HTML that you want. This could be the best option if you don't want to use HTML but it requires the most effort.

Comment: I used the remarkable plugin - it works great, thank you Yangshun

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: @YangshunTay im attempting to use the remark-external-links project in my docusaurus v2 remarkPlugins block via `require('remark-external-links')`, but it doesn't seem to be resolving. Any chance you can update this with a reference for v2?

Comment: @YangshunTay @JamesMcShane I had added a remark plugin for `remark-math` with `presets: [["@docusaurus/preset-classic",{docs: {remarkPlugins: [math],...` but changing to `remarkPlugins: [math, function(md) {extlink(md, {host: 'docs.etsycorp.com',})}],` was definitely wrong, so helpful pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @JamesMcShane I thought maybe something like: `remarkPlugins: [math, [extlink, {host: 'docs.site.com',}]],` would work in `docusaurus.config.js`'s  presets, docs block similarly to https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/packages/docusaurus-remark-plugin-npm2yarn/README.md, but I get something about a url not being a string.

Comment: @JamesMcShane for Docusaurus 2 as it's using MDX and NOT Remarkable I had to find a remark or rehype module. https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-external-links lead me to use https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-external-links but it wasn't fun.