# modify link behaviour in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, kramdown, multimarkdown

I have an itchy issue I definitely need solve.

Every time I insert a link in [my Jekyll website](https://xplosionmind.tk), independently if I write it in a Markdown file or an HTML file, I write the following:

```html
<a href="http://example.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">example</a>
```

Obviously, it's way longer, more boring and more stressful than typing

```
[example](example.com)
```

Is there a way I can add by default the `rel` and `target` attributes (maybe in the `_config.yml` file) for every link so that I can easily insert a simple `<a>` tag and then it's parsed with all the extra stuff?

I know I could insert attributes also in Markdown, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705645/12867045), but it's still quite a lot of typing...

Thanks a lot in advance, this would definitely change my game!

Comment: You may want to consider looking at this post for inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My past Jekyll project was able to leverage a fork of [Jekyll Target Blank](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank) that added `rel` and `target` attributes to `<a>` tags.

Comment: This is **great**, thanks! Does it work with GitHub Pages || Netlify?

Thanks again you saved me hours of useless typing. I love you.

Comment: @Tommi We did not use GitHub Pages or Netlify, so I don't know if `jekyll-target-blank` works with those hosting platforms.  We self-hosted our Jekyll project.

Comment: Got it. Thank you anyways. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

[Kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/) supports it this way (as you mentioned):

```
[example](example.com){:target="_blank"}{:rel="noopener noreferrer"}
```

If you want to do it for all links across your site, you'd need to write a custom plugin, which wouldn't work on GitHub Pages, or use Javascript.

Comment: If I have to write all that stuff, it doesn’t change much from HTML, I’d use that. Thanks anyway.