# open a link in a new tab with parameter using HTML in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

I am using markdown and try to open an internal link with `page_id` in a new tab.

I have tried:

`[description](my_url)` - This works but it cannot open a new tab

`[description](my_url){:target="_blank"}` - The content in `{}` brackets cannot be recognized by markdown, they are directly shown as characters on the page.

`<a href="http://url/web/#/3?page_id=96" target="_blank">` - This can open the web but still not in a new tab. Using `F12`, it returns an exception: `_ is not defined`... If I only put `http://url`, it can open in a new tab...But I need to jump to the target page...

`<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://url/web/#/3?page_id=96', '_blank')">test</a>` - This can be recognized as a hyper link and when the cursor hovers on it, it becomes a hand. But nothing happens when clicking it.

How to address this issue?

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown

Comment: `{:target="_blank"}` isn't standard Markdown. What tool are you using to generate HTML from your Markdown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create links with 'target="\_blank"' in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown)