# why can't you write some code that opens all links in a new tab?

Tags: html, hyperlink, markdown

Why do we have to write Visit link?

Or for instance, in markdown, why do we have to write link, and in that there is no way to open a new tab unless you use HTML.

So why isn't there a solution so that all links in markdown pages open in a new tab?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain more? Are you asking about how to write a link in HTML that always opens a new tab?

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for? Why the original author of whatever markdown flavor you are using did not add syntax for this? `<base target="_blank">` does exist.

Comment: What you can do depends on the markdown flavor you are using. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown

Answer (score 0):

adding the target="_blank" attribute to your anchor tag will open the link in a new tab if that's what you're after.

```
<a src="www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: When using "_blank", also use "noopener noreferrer" (look for what it means here: https://www.reliablesoft.net/noreferrer-noopener/)