# How to open links in bot framework in a seperate tab

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there a configuration in the bot framework that makes it open links in a seperate tab?

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492153/markdown-open-a-new-window-link) link, seems there is no way to specify in markdown to open a link in a new window and that it is possible using html.

We do not want to specify that long HTML configuration in each link, and we cannot call a function that does that because some of the links appear as a prompt which expects const only (so calling a function is not possible).

Therefore, we are looking for some general configuration in the bot frameowrk that would make links appear in a new window.

Comment: what channel are u using?

Comment: Webchat channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links should open in a new tab by default.  There is a GitHub issue tracking this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/454

Here is the PullRequest that fixes the issue: [configure MarkdownIt to open links in new tab](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/455)

Answer (score 1):

There is a class in bot framework named [CardAction](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/df7/_card_action_8cs_source.html).

If you want to open some link, you should have something like this :

```
List<CardAction> listButtons = new List<CardAction>();
listButtons.Add(new CardAction
{
  Value = "https://google.com",
  Type = "openUrl",
  Title = "open google",
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm looking is a setting in bot framwrok so that links open in another window by default

Comment: Can you provide more explanation what you are trying to do ?

Comment: When writing a regular context,PostAsync message I want links like this one: [text](https://url) to be opened in a new tab

Comment: You can't insert links into any messenger channel. You must use CardAction instead. Please mark this question as answered.