# pandoc: Open link in new tab

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29767900/4185785), it should be possible to use the following syntax

```
[link](url){:target="_blank"}
```

to have links opening in a new tab when using `pandoc`.

However, it seems this option is not supported as the option is not recognized when converting to html.

I am using `rmarkdown` which relies on `pandoc` in the background.

Is it possible to do so using `pandoc` and if yes, how?

Comment: This is the table describing what is available in various pandoc target outputs : https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Tabular-overview%3A-Pandoc%27s-supported-Markdown-dialects-and-extensions-enabled-by-default ; you likely need to build a new doc type to handle what you need or just craft anchors the old-fashioned way.

Comment: If you need to do this globally for HTML output, have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71230269/42659

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dropping the colon should be enough:

```
[link](https://example.org){target="_blank"}
```

Answer (score -3):

Removing "underscore" before "blank"

```
[link](https://example.org){target="blank"}
```