# Open readme.md link in new tab (GitHub)

Tags: html, github, markdown, readme

how to make a link in GitHub *readme.md* to **open link in new tab**

`[my website](www.google.com)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markdown open a new window link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492153/markdown-open-a-new-window-link)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create links with 'target="\_blank"' in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425198/can-i-create-links-with-target-blank-in-markdown)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible. Even if you use plain html "target" does not appear in the final  tag. Users can just ctrl+click to get the same behaviour.